# Python: Prevent decoding of bytearray while printing

Tags: python, arrays, encoding, byte

The following code shows that printing an bytearray makes it decode ASCII characters whenever possible.

```
>>> a = bytearray([0x0D, 0x48, 0x69])
>>> print(a)
bytearray(b'\rHi')
```

Is there an easy way to prevent the decoding of bytes and instead produce a result like this?

```
bytearray(b'\x0d\x48\x69')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution (but there's gotta be a more organic way of doing this)!

a = bytearray([0x0D, 0x48, 0x69])

print(map(hex, a))

Comment: A short and easy solution like this was exactly what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid you have to build it *by hand*:

```
def dump(x):
    return ''.join([type(x).__name__, "('",
                    *['\\x'+'{:02x}'.format(i) for i in x], "')"])
```

You can then do:

```
>>> a = bytearray('\rHi', 'ascii')
>>> print(dump(a))
bytearray('\x0d\x48\x69')
```